# web api with AngularJS http get status 0

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting an error when I am trying to send a request in AngularJS with $http.get() method and I am getting an answer with no data and status 0 in this code:

client:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['MyService']).controller('myCtrl', function ($scope ,HandleService) {

    $scope.AddCar = function () {

        HandleService.GetAll().then(function (result) {
            alert(result.data);
        }, function(err) {
            return alert(err.data);
        });

    }


});



angular.module('MyService', []).factory('HandleService',  ['$http' , function ($http) {

    return {

        GetAll: function(){

            return $http.get('http://localhost:7141/Home/GetAll').then(function (result) {

                return result.data;
            });

        }
    };

}]);
```

Server:

```
[Route("GetAll")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
        {
            List<string> names = new List<string>();

            names.Add("1");
            names.Add("2");



            var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(JArray.FromObject(names).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };

            return response;

        }
```

When I call from chrome web I get my correct data.

Comment: what does the console say

Answer (score 0):

First try this in your controller

```
    [HttpGet, Route("GetAll")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>();

        names.Add("1");
        names.Add("2");
        return Ok(names);
    }
```

assuming its WebApi2 that is. If not

```
[HttpGet, Route("GetAll")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
{
    List<string> names = new List<string>();

    names.Add("1");
    names.Add("2");

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Comment: status is still return 0